# what is the output of this code and how?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Program to understand sizeof operator:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
  char *mess[]={                         //array of pointers
    "amol is a good boy",
    "robin singh",
    "genious boy",
    "bitch please"
  };
  printf("%d",sizeof(mess));  // what does sizeof operator do?
}
```

Please explain the output of this code.

Comment: What *is* the output? What *part* don't you understand? The more specific your question, the better we can help.

Comment: also tell printf("%d",sizeof(mess[2]));

Comment: had a good chuckle at the 4th string. the sizeof() gives the size in bytes of mess pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It is the storage size in bytes of 4 pointers to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You have your answer right in your question. It has a size of an array of pointers.

So the size is `4 * size of a pointer`. (which is 32 on my system.) Your system might vary.